# Selenium Python: How to click on a <a> tag based on "onclick" text

Tags: python, selenium

So this page has several

```
<a href="#" onclick="showpage('potato.php');">...
<a href="#" onclick="showpage('carrots.php');">...
<a href="#" onclick="showpage('chicken.php');">...
<a href="#" onclick="showpage('fish.php');">...
```

of these tags. While I could do a find_elements_by_xpath and then pick the one I want, is there a way to say in specific, I want to click on the potato link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find_element_by_partial_link_text`:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("potato").click()
```

More documentation available here on find by strategies:  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html

**Edit**:  talk about misreading the question.  I thought you were looking to click on a link with the text "potato".

If you were specifically trying to look for the contents of an `onclick`, you could use something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick, 'potato.php')]").click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Richard's solution should work. Also  You could use some xpath like

```
//a/*[contains(text(),'Potato')]
```

Comment: Yea was wondering about that, what if I have potatoSoup.php and potato.php. I guess I can search by potato.php instead of potato?

Comment: Then Richards second solution will work. I also thought that the link will have text potato. In that case above solution will not work